# Every open interval of $\mathbb{R}$ contains either infinitely many or no elements in the Cantor set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-writing, cantor-set

I am thinking about a proof of the following statement:

"Every open interval of $\mathbb{R}$ contains either infinitely many or no elements in the Cantor set"

and this is what I have thought:

Let $(a,b),\ a,b\in\mathbb{R}, a<b$ be an open interval of $\mathbb{R}$ and define the Cantor set $\mathcal{C}:=[0,1]\setminus\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}G_n$, where $G_1=(\frac{1}{3}, \frac{2}{3})$ and $G_n$ for $n>1$ is
the union of the middle-third open intervals in the intervals of $[0, 1]\setminus (\bigcup_{j=1}^{n-1}G_j)$

By the definition of the Cantor set it is clear that if $(a,b)\cap [0,1]=\emptyset$ or $(a,b)$ is or is contained in a middle-third open interval in $[0,1]$ then it contains none of its elements.

Suppose now $(a,b)\cap [0,1]\neq\emptyset$ and $(a,b)$ is not nor is it contained in a middle-third open interval in $[0,1]$:
**beginning of hand-wavy argument**
then, since as $n$ increases the length of each middle-third open interval decreases (every such interval has length $\frac{1}{3^n}$) there will be, for $n$ large enough, an infinite number of middle-third open intervals in $(a,b)\cap [0,1]$ and since the endpoints of the middle-third open intervals are elements of $\mathcal{C}$ the claim follows.

---

Now, the last part of this argument is clearly non-rigorous, but I think I have got at least the idea of the proof right so I would appreciate an hint about how to rigorously prove that, in the last part of the proof, $(a,b)$ must contain an infinite number of middle-third intervals, thanks.

---

**EDIT: I have proved the statement by following the advice of the user Joe in the comments below - comment about the proof are welcome**

We first prove that the Cantor set contains no isolated points.

We can rewrite the Cantor set as $\mathcal{C}=[0,1]\setminus\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}G_n=\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}([0,1]\setminus G_n)=\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathcal{C}_n$, where $\mathcal{C}_n:=[0,1]\setminus G_n$: then $\mathcal{C}_1=[0,\frac{1}{3}]\cup [\frac{2}{3},1]$, $\mathcal{C}_2=[0,\frac{1}{9}]\cup [\frac{2}{9},\frac{1}{3}]\cup [\frac{2}{3},\frac{7}{9}]\cup [\frac{8}{9},1],\dots$ and note that, being closed, the endpoints of every interval in $\mathcal{C}_n,\ n\geq 1$ belong to $\mathcal{C}_n$ and since they are not affected by the removal of middle-third intervals in the various steps the endpoints of these intervals belong to all the $\mathcal{C}_n$ hence to $\mathcal{C}$.

Let $x\in\mathcal{C}$: then as we said for every $n\geq 1$ there exists $x_n\in\mathcal{C}\cap\mathcal{C}_n=\mathcal{C},\ x_n\neq x$ such that $|x-x_n|\leq\frac{1}{3^n}$, namely one of the two endpoints of $\mathcal{C}_n$, so we can build a sequence $(x_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ of elements of $\mathcal{C}$, all distinct from $x$, and converging to $x$; this means that no $x\in\mathcal{C}$ is an isolated point, as desired.

Let now $(a,b),\ a,b\in\mathbb{R}, a<b$ be an open interval of $\mathbb{R}$.

By the definition of the Cantor set it is clear that if $(a,b)\cap [0,1]=\emptyset$ or $(a,b)$ is or is contained in a middle-third open interval in $[0,1]$ (i.e. $(a,b)\subset\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}G_n$) then it contains none of its elements.

Suppose now $(a,b)\cap [0,1]\neq\emptyset$ and $(a,b)$ is not nor is it contained in a middle-third open interval in $[0,1]$: then there must be $x\in (a,b)\cap\mathcal{C}$ so there is some $r>0$ such that $(x-r,x+r)\subset (a,b)$. Since $x$ is not an isolated point for every $n>\log_3(\frac{1}{3})+1$ there exists $x_n\in\mathcal{C}$ such that $|x-x_n|<\frac{1}{3^n}<r$ i.e. such that $x_n\in (x-r,x+r)\subset (a,b)$ so $(a,b)$ contains infinitely many elements of the Cantor set, as desired. $\square$

Comment: FYI, questions like this in the absence of context can be difficult to answer because it's not clear what we are allowed to assume and how the Cantor set is defined. For example, probably the most basic property of the Cantor set is that it is a (nonempty) perfect nowhere dense set (indeed, such sets are often simply called "Cantor sets"), and  the property you're asking about is immediate if you know that the Cantor set is perfect. Indeed, all you need is that the Cantor set is dense in itself (i.e. each of its points is a limit point of itself).

Comment: Can you use that the Cantor set has no isolated points, or would you need to prove that also? If you can use that, you can do a proof by contradiction by assuming that there is an open interval with finitely many (but not zero) points from the Cantor set.

Comment: @Joe this looks like a promising way go patch up my argument: I'll work on it and as soon as I am done I will update my question, thanks.

Comment: "no interval contains more than one element and every one of its elements has a ternary expansion consisting of only $0$s and $2$s" --- The first part of this is not correct, since this would mean that for each element of the Cantor set you can find an interval with center that element and such that the interval contains no other points of the Cantor set, which would mean there are intervals that contain exactly one point of the Cantor set (and thus contradict what you want to prove). Also, the second part of what I quoted, while true, is not the property you really need, since **(continued)**

Comment: the set $\{0.2,\,0.2202\}$ (contains only two numbers) is closed and has measure zero and each of its elements has a ternary expansion consisting of only $0$s and $2$s, and this set certainly doesn't have the property you want to prove. An additional property you want to use is the fact that every real number in $[0,1]$ having a decimal representation consisting of only $0$s and $2$s belongs to the Cantor set. **(continued)**

Comment: Possibly one way to prove the result you want is to first prove the result holds for each endpoint of a complementary interval (= real number in $[0,1]$ having a **finite** ternary expansion consisting of only $0$s and $2$s). After this, prove that each point in the Cantor set is a limit of these "endpoint numbers". Having done this, now pick an interval. Either the interval does not contain a point of the Cantor set (i.e. the desired result is true) or the interval contains a point of the Cantor set. If the interval contains a point of the Cantor set, then it contains an "endpoint number" ...

Comment: @Joe I have tried using your hint to prove the claim and I have edited my question accordingly. If you would be so kind to check out my new proof and write what you think of it, I would gladly accept it as an answer, thanks.

Comment: After proving that the Cantor set has no isolated points, rather than talk about middle thirds, I would just say that for every $n\ge1$ there exists $x_n\in \mathcal{C}$ such that $x_n\in B(x,1/3^n)\setminus\{x\}$. Then, technically, someone might want you to show that those $x_n$, which as stated above are not necessarily distinct, take on infinitely many values. My earlier comment was to assume there was an open interval with finitely many points from $\mathcal{C}$, take one, and the minimum of the distances from that to the other (finitely many) points, then show that point is isolated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your hand-wavy argument is definitely on the right track. A couple things to think about that can make it less hand-wavy are:

- It can help to focus on and phrase things in terms of the closed intervals that are intersected to make $C$ than the middle third open intervals that are removed.
- If $(a,b)$ contains one of these closed intervals from a finite stage, then it contains all the closed intervals made from that interval. Then as you say, the endpoints of those intervals are in $(a,b)$.
- With that in mind, you will want to explain why if $(a,b)$ contains any point of the Cantor set, it contains a while finite-stage interval around the point.